# Calling a new activity while rotating the ImageView

Tags: android, xml, android-animation

I am trying out animation in android. I want to rotate the image view only without disturbing the horizontal scroll view below it. Also, when the animation is complete I want to start a new activity. I do not want to use fragments as I want to start a new activity when the flip is completed. As, of now the application works without errors but it not smooth and the Horizontal scroll view also rotates. Also, it doesn't seem like that it is rotating. When I put alpha properties in the rotate_in.xml it gives an error that "The child element must be well formatted" Kindly help.
Here are the source codes:

Layout1:

```
 LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.fromscratch.MainActivity" >


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:src="@drawable/you"
        android:id="@+id/you" >  
         </ImageView>
     <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" 
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/date"
                android:layout_width="100dip"
                android:layout_height="100dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/date" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/mission"
                android:layout_width="100dip"
                android:layout_height="100dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/mission" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/youu"
                android:layout_width="100dip"
                android:layout_height="100dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/you" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/competitionn"
                android:layout_width="100dip"
                android:layout_height="100dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/competition" />


        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Layout2:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.fromscratch.MainActivity" 
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:src="@drawable/competition"
        android:id="@+id/competition" >   
         </ImageView>




    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" 
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/date"
                android:layout_width="100dip"
                android:layout_height="100dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/date" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/mission"
                android:layout_width="100dip"
                android:layout_height="100dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/mission" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/you"
                android:layout_width="100dip"
                android:layout_height="100dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/you" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/competitionn"
                android:layout_width="100dip"
                android:layout_height="100dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/competition" />


        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

rotate_in.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<scale
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:duration="200"
    android:fromXScale="0.0"
    android:fromYScale="0.90"

    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:startOffset="500"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0" />
```

rotate_out.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<scale
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="0.0"
    android:toYScale="0.90" />
```

I use this to in the second activity
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.rotate_in, R.anim.rotate_out);

The app works perfectly fine while using the fadein and fadeout animation. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you only want to rotate the one ImageView, and not the entire contents of the Activity, then it doesn't seem like setting activity transitions is the way to go. If you tell Android to animate an activity, it's going to animate the entire thing.

One alternative would be to attach your animation to your ImageView directly. When the user clicks (or whatever trigger you are using), you could start the animation, first setting an animation listener, so when the animation finishes you launch the new activity. Something like this:

```
View you = findViewById(R.id.you);
RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation(0f, 90f);
anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        //TODO launch the other activity
        finish(); // Finish this activity
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
    }
});
you.startAnimation(anim);
```

I am creating the animation in code, but you could of course put it in XML too. Also, I am using RotateAnimation instead of ScaleAnimation, because you said you wanted to rotate it.